# Given an array of numbers, find a number to start with such that the sum is never negative

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

Given an array of integers, find the smallest number X to start with, such that adding elements of array to X, the sum is always greater than 0

If given array is {-2, 3, 1, -5}
For example, in the above array, X should be 4

Explanation:
If, we start with 4, then adding first number -2, array sum becomes 4 + (-2) = 2 (which is >0)
Now adding next element 3 to current sum which is 2, 2+ 3 = 5 (which is >0)
Adding next element 1 to new sum 5 gives, 5 + 1 = 6 (which is >0)
Adding last element -5 to new sum 6 gives 6 + (-5) = 1, which is again greater than zero.

Given an array of integers, How can I find the smallest number X?

Comment: Can X be negative? E.g. the given array could be {2}, so X = -1 would work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Yes, X can also be negative

Answer (score 2):

Find minimum of **cumulative sum** for given array.
Needed result is `1 - MinC`

```
A = [-2, 3, 1, -5]
CSum = 0
MinC = 10000000000
for x in A:
    CSum += x
    MinC = min(MinC, CSum)
Addend = 1 - MinC
print(Addend)

>>> 4
```

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks. I also wanted to know your though process in solving this if you can.

Comment: I saw that you described cumulative sum and its minimum is definitely   corresponds to needed value. Just look at your sum without "we start with 4"

Answer (score 1):

First we should check if element at **ith** position is greater than zero or not. If element is greater than zero then no problem and we can add it directly to our sum, `ans` remains unchanged. But if not greater than zero then we first check whether sum is greater than element or not. If sum is greater than `abs(arr[I])` then then we decrease our sum by `abs(arr[I])`, `ans` remains unchanged but if `abs(arr[I])` is greater than sum then we add `abs(arr[i]-sum+1)` to `ans` and initialise sum to 1.

Below is code for same:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    typedef long long ll;
    int main()
    {
        // considering x>=0(x can't take values less than 0)
        ll arr[] = { -2, 3, 1, -5};
        ll n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(ll);
        ll ans = 0; // My answer
        ll sum = 0; // current sum of elements
        for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] <= 0)
            {
                if ((sum + arr[i]) <= 0)
                {
                    ans += (abs(sum + arr[i]) + 1); //add 1 to make sum=1
                    sum = 1;
                }
                else
                    sum += arr[i];   // added because arr[i]<=0,(sum-=abs(arr[i]))
            }
            else
                sum += arr[i];
        }
        cout << ans;

        return 0;
    }
    // ans=4 for this case
```

Comment: What would happen if all elements are positive? It would not return the minimum number.

Comment: Ya thats why I had commented that ans is greater or equal to 0 .Means if all are positive my answer will be 0

Answer (score 0):

you should find miniminum subarray sum first. lets say it comes equal to k.
your answer should be k+1. you can find minimum sum here :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with the simple logic by precomputing the sum of all the elements present in the array.

Find the Sum of all the elements present in the array.

If sum equals zero return 1 as it will give smallest number on adding which we will get the total sum greater than zero.

If sum greater than zero return a negative number just less than that sum ( **handle the special case of sum == 1 seperately**)

If sum is negative then return the positive  number just one greater than the sum in magnitude.

Step 1 :  **Find the Sum of all the Elements in the array**

```
 int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
 {
         sum += arr[i];
 }
```

Step 2 : **Check  The Sum obtained and Apply the following logic**

```
if(sum == 0)
         return 1;
else if( sum < 0)
         return abs(sum)+1;
else 
        {
               if( sum == 1)
                          return 0;
               else
                         return  -(sum-1);

         }
```